# с++ android usb

Tags: c++, android, usb

пишу приложение для андроида на qml/с++. Нужно работать с USB. Как из с++ достучаться до USB в андроиде? Есть в андроиде АПИ для работы с усб, но оно на Java. Можно попробовать обернуть это апи с сипипишный код. Но как делать подобные обёртки?

Есть где-нибудь пример написания с++ обёртки для java?

Answer (score 2):

Обертки? То есть вызывать c++ код из java?

1. Пишешь нативную функцию в джаве: https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/centerix/zverus/zverus/ZverusActivity.java#L245
2. Собираешь проект. Дальше с помощью javah генеришь .h файлы: https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/javah_jni.bat , она нагенерит файлы с функциями: https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/ru_centerix_zverus_zverus_ZverusActivity.h#L143
3. Пишешь код для функции: https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/main.cpp#L112
4. Собираешь через ndkbuild в библиотеку и подключаешь к проекту. https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/centerix/zverus/zverus/ZverusActivity.java#L40

То еще развлечение, все это настроить, но результат того стоит.